# PDF written with itext 1.4 is increasing in size

Tags: java, itext

In our code, we have a functionality that a dynamically generated PDF from an external system can be viewed in the browser using iframe and also can be saved locally for which we are using itext. What we have noticed is, once the pdf is shown in browser, if we save the pdf using browser default toolbar, the size of the pdf is less as compared to when we save the pdf from code using itext. Meaning, a manual save of pdf from browser is lot lesser in size compared to save using itext. The content of the pdf is mostly text, so it is not about large image sizes.

We have already tried the compression methods of writer and stamper classes but that's only reducing the size in kbs. Whereas, the size difference between manual save and itext save is in few MBs. 
PFB the snapshot of the code that we are using. Sorry that I could not post the full code because of organization constraint and I am bit hurried to get some help here. Please let me know if the snippet is not sufficient so that I can try to provide an extracted running version.

```
    Document document = new Document();
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(inputPdfStream);

        //Get total no. of pages in the pdf file.
        int totalPages = pdfReader.getNumberOfPages();

        // Create writer for the outputStream
       PdfWriter writer = 
       PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
       PdfStamper stamper=new PdfStamper(pdfReader, outputStream);
       //Open document
       document.open();
          //Contain the pdf data.
        PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = writer.getDirectContent(); 
        PdfImportedPage page;
        document.newPage();
        page=stamper.getImportedPage(pdfReader, startPage);
        pdfContentByte.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
        writer.setFullCompression();
        stamper.setFullCompression();
        stamper.setFreeTextFlattening(true);
        pdfReader.getCatalog().remove(com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfName.METADATA);
```

Looking for some help on how to reduce the file size while saving from itext and have a size same as when done from browser.

Comment: You have two distinct objects, a `PdfWriter` and a `PdfStamper`, both writing to `outputStream`. You are lucky if the output can be opened as a pdf at all. Apparently the pdf viewer in the browser on the client side attempts to sort the hodgepodge and keep only the data for one document. You should really clean up your current code. While your at it, you can also update itext, version 1.4 is prehistoric...

Comment: Agee @mkl ...actually the code put as an example above was the product of trying multiple things and stuck in an intermediate version. But I have tried only with stamper and writer as well with same result. From some of my research it seems adobe has capabilities to save optimized pdfs which helps in reducing the size when saved from browser. But the corresponding APIs are licensed :(

Comment: Did you try `stamper.getReader().removeUnusedObjects();` ? Maybe also  `stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
stamper.getReader().removeAnnotations();
stamper.getReader().removeFields();` does help. But there have been some bugs in that area so you should really consider updating

Comment: Adobe can optimize but it usually doesn't do so unless asked to. To a certain degree it does so while repairing broken documents. I would assume that in your attempts you simply returned broken pdfs to the viewer which according to your code is plausible. On the other hand I cannot give an example on how to improve your concrete solution as I have never worked with an itext version before 2.x.

Comment: @Lonzak Thanks for your input. I have tried all those clean ups but its reducing size only in few KBs. Also, since the pdf stream is coming from external system, I dont have much control there. Yesterday I tried the trial version of adobe's datalogics API and saw it could reduce one of our pdfs from 14 MB to 4 MB with very little quality loss. I think if I spend bit more time, even that quality can be matched with tweaking some settings.  May be itext does not have those features at least at the version I am using. Not sure if upgrading also will help much.

Comment: Yes Adobe has certainly more optimization features at hand. For newer iText versions you just might try iText 2.1.7 (or better OpenPDF) or if your license allows it iText 5.X or even 7.X. So just try and see if the size gets reduced. And if not than leave it as it is or consider alternatives...